# Wudu and Coconut Oil In Hair

Tags: wudu

If I put coconut oil in my hair does that affect my wudu the next time? If it does or does not can you explain. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When performing wudu, you are not washing your hair; you are wiping water over your hair.  Hence, why your wudu would still be valid.  Even Prophet Muhammad saw used to put oil in his hair.

Here is a good description: [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eysq7MmoUtg)

Comment: Do you have any evidence for your claim?

Comment: I added the YouTube link.